# How does Home UPS Charge battery?

Tags: battery-charging, inverter, ups

I have a pure sine wave home ups with a mains 1000VA transformer in it.

Transformer is 6.7/220VAC. How does it charge a 12V battery with 20A?????????

6.7V side is connected in H bridge mosfets.

Transformer Configuration Inside UPS (Ignore C1)

[image: schematic]

I want to design a charger with high current. Thats why I am asking.

Note: Charging Works even when mains voltage is as low as 100V.

Comment: Replace the transformer with a sine wave generator and simulate? It's a pretty simple configuration.

Comment: How does simulation gonna help? All I am asking is how does battery get charged when mains voltage is close to 100VAC and transformer output 3.2 Volts??????? I heard somewhere that while charging, the bottom two mosfets do switching while upper ones are off.

Comment: Your question is about the charging the battery. Your schematic shows the inverter output stage. Why?

Comment: @Transistor:  I think if you "properly abuse" the H-bridge you can use it to charge the battery - assuming lead acid batteries and you don't mind overcharging/boiling them.

Comment: @Transistor Maybe because the same transformer is used both ways, depending if charging or working as inverter? But it is indeed confusing since "pure sine wave" was mentioned and this usually comes together with an UPS without a "short break" (when the device turns on the inverter shortly after a power failure).

Comment: A UPS doesn't need to charge its batteries with a high current.  We would usually assume that AC power is normally available, and only fails occasionally for short periods, so the UPS can take a day or more to charge the batteries after a power failure.

Comment: @Transistor It is an input stage also. There is a cicuit which senses if mains is available (Rectifier and a couple of resistors in divider configuration do this job). Then it is sensed by PIC uController which first stop the output from the ups and switch a relay to connect the output to mains (Then this same transformer serves as an input). Then it do some sort of switching to charge the battery. Thats my question, how can it charge when voltage on transformer is only around 3-4 volts assuming mains is as low as 100v.

Comment: @JRE There is no boiling/overcharging of battery in a ups which is properly designed to control charging current. And it do 3 stage charging with proper volts. All my batteries last arround 4 years at least.

Comment: @Vikas: I'd agree with you. It seems very unlikely that you could charge with such a low voltage.

Comment: @PeterBennett Right, Current is limited to 15-20A and is very safe for a 150Ah battety.

Comment: @vangelo Input and output aren't shorted when mains suddenly appears. It has a two way relay to sort that out.

Comment: Sure @VikasKumar, I never meant that the transformer is used both ways _at the same time_. The "short break" I mentioned is exactly due to the quick switch from mains to inverter, or vice-versa. As to your question, maybe if you can provide a more complete schematic we may have a better chance to help you. Oscilloscope measurements of the gates while charging the battery could also help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I'm curious about this and nobody posted an answer, I'll post this attempt to explain, to propose a discussion.

If all MOSFETs are off, they work as a bridge rectifier, using the body diodes. But since the secondary voltage is too low to charge the batteries, if both MOSFETs at the bottom are turned on briefly and quickly *at the same time*, they could implement a kind of boost converter, using the secondary of the transformer.

As an attempt to explain what I mean, please check this concept. \$V_O\$ is \$20 V_{peak}\$ when the circuit is opened. The switch is controlled by a simple \$50 kHz\$ square wave (no control loop, obviously). The diodes function as the bridge rectifier:

[image]

The rectified voltage, for the conditions simulated here, is higher then the open circuit secondary peak:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. You madey day.